# Garbled curl output with Chrome user agent

Tags: html, curl, cgi, user-agent

I have a fairly simply bash script that produces some HTML like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ENV=`echo "${QSTRING}" | sed -n 's/^.*env=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
APP=`echo "${QSTRING}" | sed -n 's/^.*app=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
echo 'Content-type: text/html'
echo ''
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
<... etc ...>
```

When I run a curl command like this, everything works fine, and the script returns a well-formatted HTML:

```
curl --request GET '<url>'
```

But when I pass the user-agent string of a Mac OS X Chrome browser, I get a garbled output:

```
curl --request GET '<url>' -A '<user-agent>'
```

The garbled output looks something like this:

```
17
  </select>
  <br><br>

45
  Delay this install by (hours from now; 0 or blank for deploy now):

68
  <input name="delay" type="text" name="delaytime">
  <input type="hidden" name="inst" value="test">

5f
  <input type="hidden" name="repo" value="test">
  <input type="hidden" name="env" value="qa">

6f
  <input type="hidden" name="app" value="web">
  <br>
  <input name="subbtn" value="Submit" type="submit"><br>

29
 <p><br>
 </p>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>

0

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 20:51:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Amazon) PHP/5.5.26
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

At the top is the middle of what would have been the expected HTML text, with some hex codes interjected.

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. I had to specify:

```
echo 'Content-encoding: UTF-8'
```

in the script.